# Google Scholar vs other academic search engines

Tags: literature-search, literature, google-scholar

1. How is Google Scholar compared to other academic search engines and catalogues such as ScienceDirect, Scopus, and universities' own online catalogues--in terms of the following?

   - **comprehensiveness of search** (i.e. can fetch all the ever published relevant titles, whether the user have access to full-texts or not)
   - **accuracy and precision of results**
   - **advanced search features**
   - **usability**
2. Are there good reasons for (or against) using Google Scholar as the **only** *literature search tool* for PhD research?
3. Does the answer of (2) depend on the research discipline?

Comment: I'll leave giving a formal answer to someone who has more to say about part 1 (for example, I've never used Scopus), but as for 2 and 3, using just one literature search tool for PhD research seems incredibly limiting.  I can only imagine doing that in a field where you never need to refer to anything that's not recent and available online.  Only a handful of fields could satisfy that, and even then restricting yourself only to Google Scholar seems silly.

Comment: The main point is specifically about "using Google Scholar alone", but not about "using any other literature search tool alone". 2 and 3 obviously depend on 1.

Comment: Regarding 2: on the contrary, I'd encourage you to use every search tool you can find.

Comment: I wouldn't count on google scholar existing 2 or 3 years from now. It's exactly the kind of product they've been "spring cleaning."

Comment: When you search commonplace names (especially Chinese names) in Google scholar, the results are messy and mostly useless. The same thing happens when you search a term which is common between two different disciplines.

Comment: One problem with Google Scholar is that you can't document the search. I can do a search on Pubmed, and tell you my search terms (and other restrictions). You can do a search and get the same results - like other research, it sometimes helps if your results are reproducible.

Comment: There are no good reasons for using X as the _only_ tool for Y, regardless of the values of X and Y.

Comment: In my experience (environmental science), Google Scholar is much more comprehensive and up to date than other catalogues, and also much faster and easier to search. On the downside, it includes some spurious and unreviewed results, has more errors in paper details such as year of publication, and does not provide DOIs.

Answer (score 10):

There has already been much scholarship on the comparison of different academic search databases. I leave it to you to ascertain the usefulness of Google Scholar versus all the other usual suspects. [Here](http://eprints.rclis.org/8605/), [here](http://crl.acrl.org/content/70/3/227.full.pdf), [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1471-1842.2012.00992.x/abstract), [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2000776/) and [here](http://www.fasebj.org/content/22/2/338.full) are some of the prime literature on this topic.

The real answer of course, to all your sub points is, ***it depends.***