# Does Google Scholar limit the length of its search terms?

Tags: research-process, google-scholar, literature-search

On researchgate, I found the [following paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Seiji_Isotani/publication/264977522_Group_Formation_Algorithms_in_Collaborative_Learning_Contexts_A_Systematic_Mapping_of_the_Literature/links/53fa0c6a0cf2e3cbf561347a/Group-Formation-Algorithms-in-Collaborative-Learning-Contexts-A-Systematic-Mapping-of-the-Literature.pdf) that describes the application of a systematic mapping. I was curious whether the describe search term could be also found using Google Scholar.

The search term is described as the following:

```
(group formation OR group creation OR group design OR group composition OR group organization OR team formation OR team creation OR team design OR team composition OR team organization) AND (collaborative learning OR cooperative learning OR cscl OR csgf OR social learning OR group learning OR team learning) AND (algorithms OR approaches OR methods OR software OR technique)
```

According to Google's search format, I changed the term like this:

```
"group formation" OR "group creation" OR "group design" OR "group composition" OR "group organization" OR "team formation" OR "team creation" OR "team design" OR "team composition" OR "team organization" "collaborative learning" OR "cooperative learning" OR cscl OR csgf OR "social learning" OR "group learning" OR "team learning" algorithms OR approaches OR methods OR software OR technique
```

Since the search does still deliver a total of **16.700** results, I recognized that something went wrong. For test purposes I added the following term at the end `"test purposes only fgfgffff"` and i still received **16.700** results instead of **0**.

The URL looks like the following:

```
https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22group+formation%22+OR+%22group+creation%22+OR+%22group+design%22+OR+%22group+composition%22+OR+%22group+organization%22+OR+%22team+formation%22+OR+%22team+creation%22+OR+%22team+design%22+OR+%22team+composition%22+OR+%22team+organization%22+%22collaborative+learning%22+OR+%22cooperative+learning%22+OR+cscl+OR+csgf+OR+%22social+learning%22+OR+%22group+learning%22+OR+%22team+learning%22+algorithms+OR+approaches+OR+methods+OR+software+OR+technique+%22test+purposes+only+fgfgffff%22&btnG=
```

However, the term in the search field got reduced:

```
"group formation" OR "group creation" OR "group design" OR "group composition" OR "group organization" OR "team formation" OR "team creation" OR "team design" OR "team composition" OR "team organization" "collaborative learning" OR "cooperative learning" O
```

Am I correct that the provided example cannot be expressed within Google Scholar?

Comment: Best place to ask is Google Scholar...

Comment: Finally found it: [blog post](http://musingsaboutlibrarianship.blogspot.com/2014/06/8-surprising-things-i-learnt-about.html) The character limit is 256. Seems like they did the research process on the 6 pages individually.

Comment: The answer givein in this related question might help you: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/google-scholar-vs-other-academic-search-engines?rq=1.